# How to use current column name in lapply function in R?

Tags: r, lapply, r-colnames

I have two data sets: The first data set contains participants' numerical answers to questions:

```
data <- data.frame(Q1 = 1:5,
                   Q2 = rev(1:5),
                   Q3 = c(4, 5, 1, 2, 3))
```

The second data set serves as a reference table where the solutions are stored:

```
ref.table <- data.frame(Question = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"),
                        Solution = c("big", "big", "small"))
```

I would like to compare the two data sets and create a new data set that contains the binary information on whether the answer was correct (1) or incorrect (0). For this, answers `1, 2, 3` correspond to `"small"`, and answers `4, 5` correspond to `"big"`.

My attempt is the following:

```
accuracy <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {ifelse(x >= 4 & ref.table$Solution[ref.table$Question == colnames(data)[x]] == "big", 1, 0)}))
```

But somehow, this only gives me the incorrect answers as 0, while the correct answers are NA.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Note I think there is a type-o in your `ref.table` - `Solution` seems like it should be `c("big", "big", small")`

Comment: Absolutely, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, loop `across` the columns, `match` the column name (`cur_column()`) with 'Question' column from 'ref.table', get the corresponding 'Solution' value, check if it is 'big' along with the value of the column `>=` 4 and coerce the logical to binary

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ +(.x >=4 & 
    ref.table$Solution[match(cur_column(), ref.table$Question)] == 
        "big")))
```

-output

```
  Q1 Q2 Q3
1  0  1  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  0
4  1  0  0
5  1  0  0
```

---

Or in `base R`, loop over the column names in `lapply`, extract the column with `[[`, the logic applied with `match` is the same as above

```
data[] <- lapply(names(data), \(nm) +(data[[nm]] >=4 & 
    ref.table$Solution[match(nm, ref.table$Question)] == "big"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added an OR argument to make sure that the numbers corresponding to the "small" condition are also accounted for: `data %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ +((.x >= 4 & ref.table$Solution[match(cur_column(), ref.table$Question)] == "big") | (.x < 4 & ref.table$Solution[match(cur_column(), ref.table$Question)] == "small"))))`